# Issue in apache virtualhost

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have an elastic load balancer which direct all the requests at port 80 to my ec2 instance where i have apache installed and i have defined the main server configuration and a virtual host.
But all request are served by the main server defined in apache httpd.conf file.

my apache configuration is having following details:
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html" - for main server

And for sub domain requests:

```
<VirtualHost p2.neptunetimesheets.com:80>
        ServerAdmin webexpertsujeet@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/neptunev2"
        ServerName p2.neptunetimesheets.com
        #ServerAlias p1.neptunetimesheets.com
        <Directory "/var/www/neptunev2">
                  Require all granted
                        AllowOverride All
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
         RewriteEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```

Is it due to the load balancer that is causing this issue ?

Comment: I would use <VirtualHost *:80> or <VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80> (with the real IP of course). ServerName is enough if you have several host.

Comment: You have 1 load balancer and 2 web servers.  But you only show us the configuration of a sub-domain web server.  Much is missing.  What is the load balancer configured to talk to?  The particular sub-domain or the ip or the main domain?    Add lots of deatils, otherwise we will not be able to help much.